# Android Studio IBus Workaround

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio, ubuntu-15.04

When I start Android Studio it gives this warning:

"Your system is using the IBus daemon which is known to cause intermittent keyboard issues with the IDE. See known issues for suggested workarounds."

I would like to use workaround #2 found on http://tools.android.com/knownissues/ibus, but I have no idea what this means:

"$ XMODIFIERS= ./bin/studio.sh"

Do I have to add this line to a config file somewhere?

Edit: [This link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78860) has been added to the knownissues/ibus page. It has some helpful information I think.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I did:

- created `studio_no_ibus.sh` script in `android-studio` directory with these contents:

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> #
> # ---------------------------------------------------------------------
> # Disable IBus input in Android Studio.
> # ---------------------------------------------------------------------
> #
>
> pushd `dirname $0` > /dev/null
> DIR=`pwd`
> popd > /dev/null
>
> XMODIFIERS= $DIR/bin/studio.sh
> ```

- `$ chmod +x studio_no_ibus.sh`(assuming you are in `android-studio` directory)

This way you can start Android Studio with IBus disabled by running the script `$ ./studio_no_ibus.sh`.

Comment: So, will thi disable ibus for android-studio only or whole system?

Comment: As far as I understand it's for Android Studio only.